# Can't end a code span with backslash in comments

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

I tried to end a code span with a backslash in a comment. It treated the ` as a literal. I tried to escape the backslash, but that didn't work either and it still treated the ` as a literal. See below and compare to the comment I will add:

Mary had a `little\` lamb.
It's fleece was `white\\` as snow.

Raw source of that:

```
Mary had a `little\` lamb.
It's fleece was `white\\` as snow.
```

Comment: Mary had a `little\` lamb.
It's fleece was `white\\` as snow.

Comment: Mary had a `little\\` lamb.
It's fleece was `white\\` as snow.

Comment: BTW adding a space is a workaround: Mary had a `little\ ` lamb.
It's fleece was `white\ ` as snow.

Comment: Obviously the problem is that the phrase should use its, not it's ;) but let `try\\`... Nope. You could try a zero width space, but I'm not sure i can create one on my mobile...

Comment: Mary had a ``little\`` lamb.
It's fleece was ``white\\`` as snow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I tried to escape the backslash, but that didn't work either and it still treated the ` as a literal.

You need to double the backticks:

```
Mary had a ``little\`` lamb. It's fleece was ``white\\`` as snow.
```

Results in:

> [image]

The above is a screenshot of [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332342/cant-end-a-code-span-with-backslash-in-comments#comment382934_332342).

Comment: I wonder what the commonmark spec says http://spec.commonmark.org/

Comment: @Braiam 1/ "Escaped characters are treated as regular characters and do not have their usual Markdown meanings" (where backslash is an escape character) and later 2/ "Backslash escapes are never needed, because one can always choose a string of n backtick characters as delimiters, where the code does not contain any strings of exactly n backtick characters. Code span backticks have higher precedence than any other inline constructs except HTML tags and autolinks.". To me that fits the observed behaviour.